# Python - execute multiple SQL queries in a array in python

Tags: python, sql, oracle

I am going to execute multiple SQL queries in python but I think since they are in array there are some extra characters like `[" "]` which `read_sql_query` function cannot execute them, or maybe there is another problem. Do anyone know how can I solve this problem?

My array:

```
array([['F_TABLE1'],
   ['F_TABLE2'],
   ['F_TABLE3'],
   ['F_TABLE4'],
   ['F_TABLE5'],
   ['F_TABLE6'],
   ['F_TABLE1'],
   ['F_TABLE8']], dtype=object)
```

My python code:

```
SQL_Query = []
for row in range(len(array)):
      SQL_Query.append('SELECT ' + "'" + array[row] + "'" + ', COUNT(*) FROM ' + array[row]) 
SQL = []
for row in range(len(SQL_Query)):
      SQL = pd.read_sql_query(SQL_Query[row], conn)
```

PS: I separated them in two `for` to see what is wrong with my code.

Also I print one of the arrays to see what is the output of my array.

```
print(SQL_Query[0])
```

The output:

```
["SELECT 'F_CLINICCPARTY_HIDDEN', COUNT(*) FROM F_TABLE1"]
```

Because of the above output I think the problem is extra characters.

It gives me this error:

```
Execution failed on sql '["SELECT 'F_TABLE1', COUNT(*) FROM F_TABLE1"]': expecting string or bytes object
```

Comment: try array[row][0] instead of array[row] or SQL_Query[row] to SQL_Query[row][0]

Comment: Thank You, But when I wrote array[row][0] it just gave a one row, I want the whole 8 rows.(the last row)

Comment: inside your first for loop replace this line:SQL_Query.append('SELECT ' + "'" + array[row] + "'" + ', COUNT(*) FROM ' + array[row]) with SQL_Query.append('SELECT ' + "'" + array[row][0] + "'" + ', COUNT(*) FROM ' + array[row][0])

Comment: and after that your can also change inside the second for loop:SQL = pd.read_sql_query(SQL_Query[row], conn) to SQL = pd.read_sql_query(SQL_Query[row], conn) to SQL = pd.read_sql_query(SQL_Query[row][0], conn)

Comment: yeah I did that, but for the second loop, when I print the data frame, it just gave me the last row.

Comment: the problem is you are assigning the value you should append it.you declare SQL as a list then you can just append.

Comment: try to change this SQL = pd.read_sql_query(SQL_Query[row], conn)  to SQL.append(pd.read_sql_query(SQL_Query[row], conn))

Comment: please do not forget to upvote the part of the comment that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi reason for this kind of an issue is when getting a numpy array value like `array[row]` will resultant in a **numpy object**. Even though in basic array terms it looks like the way numpy behaves differently. use [item](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html) method to overcome the issue.

Based on your array I have written a sample code in there I'm only referring to the same array object instead of columns and tables.

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([['F_TABLE1'],
   ['F_TABLE2'],
   ['F_TABLE3'],
   ['F_TABLE4'],
   ['F_TABLE5'],
   ['F_TABLE6'],
   ['F_TABLE1'],
   ['F_TABLE8']], dtype=object)

SQL_Query = []
for row in range(len(array1)):
      SQL_Query.append("SELECT  \'{0}\',COUNT(*) FROM {1}".format(str(array1.item(row)),str(array1.item(row))) ) 
print(SQL_Query)
```

feel free to use two array objects for selecting SQL columns and tables.

And using '' while selecting a column name in a query is not recommended. I have included that in this answer because I haven't got any idea about the destination database type.

Answer (score 0):

I change my query to this(putting * helped me to omit other characters):

```
SQL_Query = []
for row in range(len(array)):
     SQL_Query.append('SELECT ' + "'" + array[row] + "'" AS tableName + ', COUNT(*) AS Count FROM ' + array[row]) 
SQL = []
for row in range(len(SQL_Query)):
     SQL.append(pd.read_sql_query(*SQL_Query[row], conn))  
result = []
for item in SQL:
     result.append(item)
result = pd.concat(result)
result
```

My output:

| tableName | Count |
| --- | --- |
| F_TABLE1 | 20 |
| F_TABLE2 | 30 |
| F_TABLE3 | 220 |
| F_TABLE4 | 50 |
| F_TABLE5 | 10 |
| F_TABLE6 | 2130 |
| F_TABLE7 | 250 |